# My simple prgram does not complete and exit as long as activemq connection doesn't closed

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I write a simple program by `ActiveMQ` as following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory conFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        final QueueConnection connection = conFactory.createQueueConnection();
        final Session session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        final Destination destination = new ActiveMQQueue("MJ_SAF");
        final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

        Message message = session.createTextMessage("test");
        message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, 20);
        message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_PERIOD, 1);
        message.setIntProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_REPEAT, 1);
        producer.send(message);
}
```

when I executing this program, message send for `ActiveMQ` broker properly but my program don't exit and stay running .
When I add `connection.close();` statement to end of above program, my program complete and exit properly.

My question is: What is reason of this behavior?

Comment: take a thread dump and see what it is waiting on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are any connections open, the (AMQ-)assigned threads that handle reading and writing messages from/to these connections keep the VM running (these are no daemon threads).

You can see the threads when debugging your program.

Comment: Thanks, I understand `ActiveMQ` threads isn't daemon so it's keep the JVM running.